# Como passar dados de um Pager/Fragment para outra Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estou criando uma activity que possui **Swipe Views (ViewPager)** e gostaria de saber como faço pra passar dados do fragment para outra activity, já que sempre se pede métodos estáticos. Por exemplo, passar a posição de uma `listView` para outra activity:

```
public class Bebidas extends Activity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
 * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
 * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

static ListView lista;
static Typeface fonte, fonte2;
static ImageButton direita, esquerda;
int position;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beb);


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bebidas, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);    
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beb, container,
                false);     
        int fragment = getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);


        lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        switch(fragment) {

        case 1:


            lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                                                    // desejo salvar a posição do clique e mandar para outras activities
                }

            });

            break;

        case 2:

            lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {

            //desejo salvar a posição de clique e mandar para outras activities
                }

            });

            break;

        }


        return rootView;
    }
}   

public void onClick(View v){

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.proximaActivity:

            Intent nova = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(nova);



        break;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Poste também, o código de inicialização da `Activity` alvo. Na intent que você cria para iniciar, você pode passar parâmetros também.

Comment: @Walkim: estou querendo passar com sharedPreferences, pois uso o mesmo dado em várias activitys.. vou testar com o intent pra ver se da a mesma coisa. Quanto ao código, estou usando pra testes o "hello world" do android com viewPager mesmo

Comment: Ah sim, por `Intent` seria apenas de uma `Activity` para outra, `SharedPreferences` tem a semântica de ser usado para guardar preferências de usuário. Há outra alternativa, que seria guarder na instância global da `Application`, ou até em um `Service`. Ai tudo depende do caso.

Comment: @Walkim: postei o exemplo que estou tentando trabalhar, alguma dica?

Comment: Se você pretende usar a posição do `ListView` em diversas `Activities` talvez você possa ir repassando esse valor entre as `Activities` usando o `Intent` ou deixar essa posição na instância da `Application`. As duas são válidas...

Comment: Mas ao clicar na listView, não é mudado de activity (Bem lembrado, esqueci de adicionar um botão para mudar de activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, o melhor que consegui fazer até agora, e que considero como resposta à minha pergunta, foi criar um sharedPreferences dentro do viewPager, ficando assim:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
 * fragment.
 */
private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

/**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
 */

public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);    
    return fragment;
}

public PlaceholderFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beb, container,
            false);     
    int fragment = getArguments().getInt(
            ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);


    lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    switch(fragment) {

    case 1:


        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                                               onSavePosition(position);
            }

        });

        break;

    case 2:

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {

        onSavePosition(position);
            }

        });

        break;

    }


    return rootView;
}
//Método para salvar a posição
protected void onSavePosition(int position) {
        getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("preferencias_1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor ed = prefs.edit();
        ed.putInt("posicao", position);
        ed.commit();
    }
}   

public void onClick(View v){

switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.proximaActivity:

        Intent nova = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextActivity.class);
        startActivity(nova);



    break;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou com intent?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(fragment.getActivity(),ActivityQueRecebeOsDados.class);
intent.putExtra("dados",objetoComOsDados(String,Int... *Tem que implementar Serializable));
fragment.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

E na activity você pega eles:

```
if(getArguments().containsKey("dados")){
     Classe  objetoComOsDados= (Classe) getArguments().get("dados");
}
```

Se for para pegar os dados na activity que está utilizando o ViewPager, você pode tentar assim:

```
Fragment fragment =  mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());    
Classe objetoComOsDados = fragment.getDados();
```

Comment: Intent é melhor que sharedPreferences? até onde sei, o intent salva os dados apenas enquanto a aplicação está ligada, certo? (Não sei muito sobre intents, perdão)